# $n,a,b \mathbb \in \mathbb Z^+$ , such that $n\mid a^n-b^n$ ; to show $n\mid \frac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let  $n,a,b \in \mathbb Z^+$ be such that $n\mid a^n-b^n$ , then how to prove that $n\mid {\dfrac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}}$ ?

My try :

$d=\gcd(n,a-b),$ so $d \mid{\dfrac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}}.$ Also $\,n \mid(a-b)\left({\dfrac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}}\right),\;$  so $\;\dfrac nd\mid\dfrac {(a-b)}d\Big({\dfrac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}}\Big)$.

Now, since $\gcd\left(\dfrac nd ,\dfrac {(a-b)}d \right)=1,\;$ so $\dfrac nd\mid{\dfrac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}},\;$ it follows that $\;\operatorname{lcm}\left(d, \dfrac nd \right)\mid {\dfrac {a^n-b^n}{a-b}}.$

But then  I am stuck , Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First do the case where $n$ is a prime power.

> **Further hint:** By induction on $k$, if $p$ is prime, then $p^m\mid a-b$ implies $p^{m+k}\mid a^{p^k}-b^{p^k}$ for all $k$. (Use binomial expansion in the induction step.)

Then conclude for composite $n$.

> **Further hint:** If $p^k\mid n$, write $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=\frac{a^n-b^n}{a^{n/p^k}-b^{n/p^k}}\cdot\frac{a^{n/p^k}-b^{n/p^k}}{a-b}$

Comment: If I have more time I can elaborate on this but here are the main ideas already.

Comment: where are we using $n|a^n-b^n$ ?

Comment: In the part where $n$ is a prime power it is needed in the case where $p\nmid a-b$.